# Magento - add custom "Widget Options"

Tags: magento

It is possible to add custom "Widget Options" (as input text fields) in a new Widget Instance ?

If yes how can I do that ?

[edit]
I want also to know if it possible to uses a extra table from database to store data from text fields.
[/edit]

I'm using Magento version 1.4.2

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Widget options are defined in the widget's `widget.xml` file.  All you have to do is add a new entry in the `<parameters />` tag and it will appear in the widget interface in the administration area.  There is a [good tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-magento-widget-part-2) on the Magento website that'll walk you through, pretty much, everything you need to know on widgets.

Comment: Where could I find more info about the widgets.html options?

Comment: I always find http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-magento-widget-part-2 a good reference.

Comment: Unfortunately provided link doesn't work anymore, could you update?